# Webcam application:overload resolution failed

Tags: javascript, overload-resolution

I have this code for a webcam application that has error which is :overload resolution failed.

```
const video=document.getElementById('webcam');
const canvas=document.getElementById('photo');
const ctx=canvas.getContext('2d');
function getVideo() {
   navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({audio:false, video:true}).then(localMediaStream=>{
video.srcObject=window.URL.createObjectURL(localMediaStream);
video.play();
});}
  function paint() {
    const width=video.videoWidth;
    const height= video.videoHeight;
    canvas.width=width;
    canvas.height=height;
   setInterval(function (){ctx.drawImage(video,0,0,width,height)},16);

  } 
  video.addEventListener('canplay',paint());
 getVideo();
```